# Does Tony Soprano need permission from the other families to have people made?

Tags: the-sopranos

Does Tony Soprano need permission to have people made even though he is the boss of the family? In season 1, while Jackie Aprile is in the hospital when he is still a capo he says to Christopher the books are closed and they are not accepting any new members.

Comment: Technically, he wasn't even the boss *later*. Junior was (though in name only, for the most part).

Answer (score 4):

If Tony was the boss (and I'm pretty sure he wasn't "officially" the boss until Uncle Junior died), he could "make" Chris.  All he would need was a sponsor.  However, it's true that Mafia families only "open the books" at certain times, so it's very possible the books were closed at that time.  However, there are certain codes a made man has to live by [1]:

1. Be loyal to members of the organization. Do not interfere with each other’s interest. Do not be an informer.
2. Be rational. Be a member of the team. Don’t engage in battle if you can’t win.The directive extends to personal life.
3. Be a man of honor. Respect womanhood and your elders.
4. Be a stand-up guy. Keep your eyes and ears open and your mouth shut. Don’t sell out.The ‘stand-up guy’ shows courage and ‘heart.’ He does not whine or complain in the face of adversity, including punishment, because ‘If you can’t pay, don’t play.’
5. Have class. Be independent. Know your way around the world.

It's possible (or probable) that Tony knew Christopher couldn't live up to that.

[1] http://www.nationalcrimesyndicate.com/become-made-man/

Answer (score 1):

Definitely NO! Once Tony becomes the *de facto* Boss, he can declare "ex cathedra" that "the books" are now again "open" and induct anyone he likes. He does not have to ask anyone's permission.

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with the show, but if such a thing happens, or if there's more "evidence" towards it, it would be nice to [edit] it in, to make for a better post :)